# CustomListview Volley with Image doesn't works in real device

Tags: android, listview, android-volley

Someone, help me with this problem. i have stuck in 3 days because this problem -_-!

i can make listview with image and text using volley library, its works in emulator (i use genymotion emulator) the image and text show. but when i run it in my device (android Jelly 4.3.0) the listview is empty. the layer is blank (empty). i don't know why.

heres my piece code

```
public class DaftarBarang_Layout extends Activity{

private List<Produk> produkList = new ArrayList<Produk>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ServerRequest serverRequest;
JSONArray member = null;
private static final String url = "http://192.168.117.1:808/Koen_CI/index.php/daftar_barang_control";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.daftarbarang_layout);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, produkList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBackDaftarBarang);        
    setBehavior();

 // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest produkReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Produk produk = new Produk();
                                produk.setNamaProduk(obj.getString("nama_produk"));
                                produk.setHargaProduk(obj.getString("harga_produk"));
                                produk.setFotoProduk(obj.getString("foto_produk"));
                                Log.d("TAG", "TAG : " + produk.getNamaProduk());    

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                produkList.add(produk);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(produkReq);
}
```

im sure the url is fine, and image return is http://192.168.117.1:808/Koen_CI/gambarbaju/batik.jpg.

the problem is, why in real device the listview is not show, but in emulator the listview is show..

sorry for my bad english, but thanks anyway.. :)

heres my CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Produk> produkItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Produk> produkItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.produkItems = produkItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return produkItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return produkItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Produk p = produkItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(p.getFotoProduk(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(p.getNamaProduk());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Harga: " + p.getHargaProduk());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Have you added permission for internet access?

Comment: yes, i have added internet access in my android manifest

Comment: Could you post your adapter code? Or wherever you have your imageloader call

Comment: i edited my question, theres my customListAdapter..

Comment: Thanks, do you get any sort of error in logcat?

Comment: thanks sir because you read my problem, but the problem is solved now.
because Mr. Ishrat told me to add this code:

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: No problem! Glad it's solved, Volley can be such a pain... You may consider Picasso, I've been switching all my apps to Picasso due to it's simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your onCreate or init method.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

If this doesn't work please post logcat showing warning or error.

Comment: i will try, but i can't see the logcat. because my device is not connected in laptop. i just install it in device and connect via connectify-me

Comment: Then please try to connect your device in debugging mode, this will definitely solve your problem, without logCat ,Any one can't understood your problem, only ideas here...

Comment: hell yeah, you save my day sir!! its work like charm..

how do you know if i must add that code?
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: If we perform network operation on UI thread in API >9 then it throw NetworkOnMainThreadException, prevent to block UI to resolve this we need to put this code.
Thanks for accepting my answer.